# Windows command that deletes files with this naming format that are older than 14 days

Tags: windows

I have several files named like yyyymmdd-hhmiss.JobActivity2Reportyyyymmdd.csv.

I need a Windows command (a single command preferably, not a CMD file) that deletes files with this naming format that are older than 14 days.  I would put this command into a Tidal(Scheduler) job to keep the Archive directory cleaned up.  Also, I want  to use the timestamps on the file (and not the timestamps encoded into the file name) to decide what to delete – it’s possible multiple files could come in on the same day for different days – for example, we may get Saturday, Sunday, and Monday files on Monday.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can the "single command" be a PowerShell invocation?

Comment: I don't have admin privileges to change the execution policy for windows powershell. so cannot use powershell cmds.

Comment: Even with a 'Restricted' (default) execution policy, you should be able to run commands, e.g. `powershell -command "& Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {($_.LastWrite -gt '4/1/2013') -and ($_.Name.Contains('JobActivity2Report'))}" | Remove-Item -force`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Its saying Remove-Item is not recognized as an internal command. Also where will I define the path of the folder where I will be deleting files, like \\ProcessFolders\I_STAGE\SrcFiles\Archive. Thanks Again.

Comment: Sorry about that. I put the ending quote in the wrong place. I added the corrected version (with a specific directory) as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can make this happen in one command using standard shell tools.

Try:

```
powershell -command "& Get-ChildItem 'C:\MyStuff' | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)) -and ($_.Name.Contains('JobActivity2Report'))} | Remove-Item -force"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I later figured out ending quote was issue, but then I got stuck with path, I was adding "-path C:\MyStff" after Get-Children which was not working. But the one you posted works great.thanks again.

Comment: One last question I will have to delete  files older than 14 days everytime the scheduler run. Do I need to change '4/1/2013' everytime, or can I use something like adDays ? to make it automated

Comment: I had just used that date as an example. I updated the answer to use `Get-Date` so that you don't have to worry about changing anything.